# Measurements of the pressure drop across wind turbines?

Tags: pressure, renewable-energy

Mathematical analyses of wind turbines show that a discontinuous pressure drop happens at the rotor plane. I am looking for measurements of this effect, but I could not find any. Do you know any (measured) data that show how (and how strong) the pressure changes?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have gone through some data and it suggests that the pressure drop is in the order of few pascals - from 10 to 100 Pascals for large wind turbines.You can have a look at this paper for better understanding :- CFD Study on Aerodynamic Power Output Changes with
Inter-Turbine Spacing Variation for a 6 MW Offshore
Wind Farm